# Problem installing VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, software-sources

When I try to install VirtualBox I get this message:

CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 12.10 *Quantal Quetzal* - Release i386 (20121017.2)' is required

I do not know what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to /etc/apt/sources.list and delete the line `deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted`.

Comment: I need root permission to do that, right?

Comment: Yes, use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` (or use any other editor on command line you like) or (with a GUI) `gksudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list`.